# How to fix Error:1722 RPC server unavailable in c++ program using winevt.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, active-directory, rpc

I have two windows 10VM and a windows server 2016 vm as active directory-domain controller created in hyper-v, they are connected to host network using NAT. I have looked out for several solutions, and have enabled appropriate permissions in the firewall and group policy editor and added all users and computers to the event log readers group and remote management users group from the domain controller.
I can access event logs of the second windows 10 VM from the first through powershell (get-winevent)and through event viewer, but when I write a program using c++, the EvtOpenSession function gives error:1722 RPC server unavailable. Is there any special proceedure to enable c++ code to access logs from remote computer?

This is my code for EvtOpenSession, am I missing something in the code, or is there anything else to be done to make this work (like messing up with the registry, firewall, policy etc in local user or domain adminstrator) ?

```
EVT_HANDLE hRemote = NULL;
EVT_RPC_LOGIN Credentials;
RtlZeroMemory(&Credentials, sizeof(EVT_RPC_LOGIN));

Credentials.Server = (LPWSTR)"VIRTUAL\\DESKTOP-local02";
Credentials.Domain = (LPWSTR)"VIRTUAL.HYPERVSERVER";
Credentials.User = (LPWSTR)"VIRTUAL\\Administrator";
Credentials.Password = (LPWSTR)"Vadmin12345#";
Credentials.Flags = EvtRpcLoginAuthNegotiate;
hRemote = EvtOpenSession(EvtRpcLogin, &Credentials, 0, 0);
SecureZeroMemory(&Credentials, sizeof(EVT_RPC_LOGIN));
```

note: I tried using user credentials , and administrator credentials, both are giving the same error[1722], wrong credentials are giving error:1825.

Comment: There is nothing C++ specific about your question. You'd have these issues with *any* programming language.

Comment: I know, I've faced RPC errors Soo many times, I've rectified them by changing permissions in the firewall, even after all of that, this program is giving the same error. Any tips on how to solve this ?

Comment: It's been bothering me Soo much since I had the same issue while using powershell remoting to access remote logs, the firewall permissions helped to get rid of the error, but the same permissions don't seem to apply for my c++ program

Comment: Why are you casting narrow strings?

Comment: That is what visual studio accepts for the EVT_RPC_LOGIN structure, any other type and it won't compile, in the Microsoft documentation, the typedef given is LPWSTR for this structure

Comment: Try prefixing your string literals with `L`, e.g. `L"VIRTUAL\\DESKTOP-local02"`

Comment: I have tried that, it gives the same error

Comment: @selvaganesh Does your C++ program running on the same machine with your VMs?

Comment: @Rita, Han, I have 3 vms set up in my machine, one is configured as a AD-DC, second VM is a windows 10 VM running the program, 3rd VM is a windows 10 VM from which I'm trying to get the logs from.

Comment: @selvaganesh Have you tried get the logs of one VM from your physical machine instead of a VM? Can it reproduce the same error?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, still the same error with the program, I can still use powershell remoting and event viewer from the host machine to get logs from the vm. I know it's just gonna turn out to be a minor permission issue in the VM, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @selvaganesh Do you use DockerNAT? What's your physical machine's and VM's OS version?

Comment: I'm using the hyper-v default NAT switch for the 3 vms, one is Windows server 2016, other 2 VMs are windows 10 pro, host machine is also windows 10 pro

Comment: I also figured out that configuring the VM server to act as the default dns for the other 2 VMs and isolating the network traffic through the VM server allows me to eliminate the RPC error, but then, that's a lot of fuzz, reconfiguring the network adapters on each of the VMs seperately.

Comment: @selvaganesh There is a [support document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2102154/active-directory-replication-error-1722-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable) of the same error you can try following these steps to narrow down what's cause of yours.

Comment: Thank you for the resource, I'll look into it